# pointerHover is not being called?

Tags: pointers, codenameone

In the eclipse simulator environment, I don't seem to be receiving any
pointerHover calls on my components.  Is there something I need to do
to arm them?

[edit/response]
No one will find it acceptable to deliver desktop applications that don't support mouse movement input.

Likewise, there are many new input devices on the horizon which will require specialized support, but will all expect mouse simulation to be the baseline.   For example gesture capture by Kinect, leap motion or VR headsets will need to feed standard events to applications that have not been specifically rewritten to use them.

Answer (score 0):

We don't support those events since there is no pointer hover on the device. We might support it in a future case for desktop builds but even then the simulator will not send those events.

We might support this for the new Apple 3d touch API although I think this might be too simplistic.

This API was originally introduced for the blackberry 5 device which had a "click screen" that allowed hovering and clicking.

You should use `pointerDrag` events which are more representative of all devices.